# A way to versioning code based on mutable API?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm developping mods for the game Minecraft using an API (Forge/MCP). The API often changes. Currently, I'm using git and I've created one branch per version.
Each time a new API version is available, I create a branch following theses steps :

- Create new branch (more recent API version) from the last branch (old more recent API version)
- Commits modification to make my new branch compatible with new API version
- Commits new features/bugfixes on the created branch until a new API version is available.

I have to develop new features, bugfixes etc ... but I want to apply it to each branch. I can't use merge, because I don't want to merge first commits (step 2), only next commits (step 3).

Is there a way to do that ?

If there is, I'll have to downgrade each commits (from step 3) to be compatible with older API version.

That's all I found currently, but I'm a bit confused because it doesn't seems to be a elegant solution anyways. Do you have any idea about how could I manage my code for it to be more maintainable ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to apply changes from a different branch on top of your checked-out branch.

If that is not what you prefer, you could possibly make .patch or .diff files out of the commits and apply that on top of the desired branch.